# The final Boundary Condition is Unknown, Is Backward Euler is still valid to be implemented?

Tags: numerical-modelling, numerics, stability

I am working on conductive polymer modeling and supposed to do one-dimensional diffusion model in the thickness of the polymer, however, due to the small value of thickness in micro, when I use the forward approach it leads to instability, no matter how I decrease the number of nodes.

I have to use Backward Euler to counter this issue, however, due to the nature of our system, we can only know the initial boundary condition and not the final value, how I can solve this issue.

The question: Is there any alternative techniques I can use in numerical analysis while the final boundary condition is unknown?

**The mathematical modeling:**
For modelling the system, I am using RC transmission line, the mathematical description here: http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/trans/Infinite.html
[image]

Comment: Backward Euler (or implicit euler) does not require knowledge of the final bound conditions or values. You should read about the actual derivation and implementation of the backward euler method.

Comment: Yes, I read it carefully in this helpful link: http://hplgit.github.io/num-methods-for-PDEs/doc/pub/diffu/html/slides_diffu-1.html

Comment: If you read it carefully and understood it, you wouldn't have this posted this question as the link makes it clear it does not step back in time

Comment: In this example they set final values to zero or one, in my case this isnot true in my case.

Comment: they do not set final values there, they set the boundary conditions at each time step/the fixed boundary conditions, you can do that too.

Comment: I dont have the values of boundary conditions, thats why I cannot implement it in my case.

Comment: I am sorry, I think you dont understand my question.

Comment: what do you mean by you have no boundary conditions? are you saying you need to solve a problem without boundary or initial conditions? how about you post the actual mathematical description of the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question and hope it is helpful. I only have the initial conditions at the clamping point v[0] ( voltage), but I don't have any rudimentary idea how voltage at the tip which V[n] is unknown. I did not get set the boundary conditions at each time step/the fixed boundary conditions, maybe I understand what is written the link falsely, but the author writes explicitly, that boundary conditions at n=0, and n=3 is unknown and equal zero.

Comment: That is not a mathematical description, if you don't have one, how can we help and how do you expect to solve the problem?

Comment: I have added the link for the mathematical description ' RC transmission line', however, in my example as I have illustrated in my question, I only know the voltage at the clamping point of the artificial muscle actuator.

Comment: Hi, there. I assume that you are supposed to model and simulate the conductive properties of your polymer. If you are in a lab, the only way to do that is to connect the ends of it to some sort of connector. In order to do a numerical Simulation, you *have* to have certain boundary conditions. Lets say you connect one end of your conductor to 1V and the other to a good conductor connected to ground. Then you would have boundary conditions! What are these in your case? Do you really need a time dependent simulation? (i.e. are you testing your polymer with sinosoidal signals?)

Comment: @MPIchael, I would certainly do that  for blackbox modelling since it is quite hard to measure voltage at the tip of the actuator, the idea we need to know the value of voltage at tip so that we can know force.

Comment: @EMP, I do understand the voltage at the clamping point changes, however to set the value of the second point, the example here as an examole;   b[i] = -u_1[i]
    b[0] = b[Nx] = 0,  source http://hplgit.github.io/num-methods-for-PDEs/doc/pub/diffu/html/slides_diffu-1.html

Comment: I have added an image to show that boundary conditions are set for point 0 and n in space, in my case I have point 0 which is dynamic, but I dont know any thing about n point in space, I would be grateful if someone would explain.

Comment: In the image you provided, what do the axes mean? Is the rect in the middle the polymer? Could you sketch a little diagram of how your clamps are connected and where you are measuring etc.?